# Marking a key as complete in a GroupBy | Dataflow Streaming Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

To our Streaming pipeline, we want to submit unique GCS files, each file containing multiple event information, each event also containing a key (for example, *device_id*). As part of the processing, we want to shuffle by this *device_id* so as to achieve some form of *worker to device_id* affinity (more background on why we want to do it is in [this another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535170/google-dataflow-pipeline-with-instance-local-cache-external-rest-api-calls). Once all events from the same file are complete, we want to reduce (GroupBy) by their source GCS file (which we will make a property of the event itself, something like *file_id*) and finally write the output to GCS (could be multiple files).

The reason we want to do the final GroupBy is because we want to notify an external service once a specific input file has completed processing. The only problem with this approach is that since the data is shuffled by the *device_id* and then grouped at the end by the *file_id*, there is no way to guarantee that all data from a specific *file_id* has completed processing.

Is there something we could do about it? I understand that Dataflow provides *exactly_once* guarantees which means all the events will be eventually processed but is there a way to set a deterministic trigger to say all data for a specific key has been grouped?

---

**EDIT**
I wanted to highlight the broader problem we are facing here. The ability to mark 
 *file-level* completeness would help us checkpoint different stages of the data as seen by external consumers. For example,

- this would allow us to trigger *per-hour* or *per-day* completeness which are critical for us to generate reports for that window. Given that these stages/barriers (hour/day) are clearly defined on the input (GCS files are date/hour partitioned), it is only natural to expect the same of the output. But with Dataflow's model, this seems impossible.
- Similarly, although Dataflow guarantees *exactly-once*, there will be cases where the entire pipeline needs to be restarted since something went horribly wrong - in those cases, it is almost impossible to restart from the correct input marker since there is no guarantee that what was already consumed has been completely flushed out. The **DRAIN** mode tries to achieve this but as mentioned, if the entire pipeline is messed up and draining itself cannot make progress, there is no way to know which part of the source should be the starting point.

We are considering using *Spark* since its micro-batch based Streaming model seems to fit better. We would still like to explore Dataflow if possible but it seems that we wont be able to achieve it without storing these checkpoints externally from within the application. If there is an alternative way of providing these guarantees from Dataflow, it would be great. The idea behind broadening this question was to see if we are missing an alternate perspective which would solve our problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is actually tricky. Neither Beam nor Dataflow have a notion of a per-key watermark, and it would be difficult to implement that level of granularity.

One idea would be to use a stateful DoFn instead of the second shuffle. This DoFn would need to receive the number of elements expected in the file (from either a side-input or some special value on the main input). Then it could count the number of elements it had processed, and only output that everything has been processed once it had seen that number of elements.

This would be assuming that the expected number of elements can be determined ahead of time, etc.

Comment: It is safe to assume that every event in the input GCS file will generate exactly one event to the output - so we know the expected number of events once the data is read.

Comment: It is safe to assume that every event in the input GCS file will generate exactly one event to the output - so we know the expected number of events once the data is read. I have a few follow up questions
[1] IIRC, Stateful ParDos work per-key-per-window - assuming there is no windowing which means its a single global window, it still works on a per-key basis - so we would need the shuffle to `GroupyBy` the _file_id_, right?

<continued in next comment>

Comment: <continued from previous comment>
[2] The side-input generated after the initial read of the GCS file will be a `Map<file_id, event_count>` - I know that side-input or `PCollectionView` are also immutable - so how would Beam/Dataflow manage garbage collection for old `file_id`? Like, if all data for a particular `file_id` arrived and the external service has been notified, since the `file_id -> event_count` is no longer needed, how can this be removed so that the side input `PCollectionView` does not keep growing infinitely?

<continued in next comment>

Comment: <continued from previous comment> [3] You mentioned about sending the data as a special value in the main input - I dont understood how we could single out some specific values from a `PCollection` with some special meaning

Comment: Side inputs are not currently garbage collected. Instead, you could create a class `CountOrInput<E>` that represents either a number or a value of type `E`. Then in the Stateful `DoFn`, you look to see if the input is a Count, in which case you now know how many elements to wait for, or an element, in which case you increment the number of elements you've seen.