# Caching in Apache Beam: Static variable vs Stateful processing

Tags: java, caching, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm adding a caching functionality to one of the DoFns inside a Dataflow Pipeline in Java. The DoFn is currently using a REST client to send a request to an endpoint (that charges based on number of request, and the response will change roughly every hour) for every input element, and what I want to achieve is to cache the response from the endpoint, and have it expiries every 15 mins.

I found two ways to do this: one from a similar [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535170/google-dataflow-pipeline-with-instance-local-cache-external-rest-api-calls) that suggested to use static variable to host a cache service (I used guava for caching). However I wasn't sure how to update the expiry from outside of the DoFn.

Another approach that I found is to use [stateful processing](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html) to store a hash that keep track of the requests and responses, and use a TimerSpec to clear the "cache" every 15 mins. Although it appears that there is no way to set a timer for each element in the cache.

I haven't tried the second approach yet. While I'm going to implement it, I wonder if someone had running into similar situations, and has any suggestions, or has better approaches.

Comment: REST response changes roughly every hour but you want it to expire every 15 mins?

Comment: yes, cause the response is not changed based on a fixed schedule, and it possible that it sends a response to be cached right before it gets an update

Answer (score 0):

> However I wasn't sure how to update the expiry from outside of the DoFn.

Do you need to? `DoFn` does a lookup first and if the entry already expired it issues a request and updates cache. Cache reads & write need to be thread-safe.

> Although it appears that there is no way to set a timer for each element in the cache.

You can probably sets a timer that scan the entire cache every X minutes and refresh expired entries. However, if your state is not keyed using a global state like this will limit the parallelism of your pipeline.

Comment: To your first question, it is optional, but I would like to set different expiries based on each configuration set by `DataflowPipelineOptions`. And to your second point, it is an interesting idea, it not exactly what I was thinking feels bit overkill, but may just do the work. I wonder if you have tried before and know how this approach would perform, as every update is essentially rewriting the hashmap

Comment: 1. You can store a `lastUpdateTimestamp` along with your cached data. 2. You can do the same without scanning the entire cache.

Comment: Not exactly sure about "without scanning the entire cache". I was assuming to use a `ValueState<HashMap<String, Object>>` to store the cache, so every `ValueState.write()` would overwrite the entire HashMap

Comment: There is `MapState` though it's not supported by all the runners.